# Compare dataframe column values in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need help on dataframe value comparison.
I have dataframe with n rows.I want compare where last three col values should be greater than previous

```
if(data["percent"].item()>data["percent"].shift().item()>data["percent"].shift(-1).item()):
```

I am getting below error while executing.

```
if(data["persent"].item()>data["persent"].shift().item()>data["persent"].shift(-1).item()):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 827, in item
    return self.values.item()
ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar
```

Comment: Remove the `.item()` everywhere.

Comment: if(data["persent"]>data["persent"].shift()>data["persent"].shift(-1)):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 892, in __nonzero__
0.740581756771121
    .format(self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().